# Multithreading Issue - JAVA thread.wait() on method that has to be used

Tags: java, multithreading, robotics, lejos-nxj

I am currently working on a robot. I use an EV3 lego brick. My goal is to travel from point A to B using a method travelTo(x,y) using the shortest path. This method is in a thread name Drive, which contains all the methods used to control the movements of my robot (turnTo(double angle), travel(double distance), travelTo(double x, double y), changeSpeed(int newSpeed)...). 
I have another thread called ObstacleAvoidance which is supposed to stop the thread Drive if there is an obstacle in front and start avoiding the obstacle using P Controller technique to follow the obstacle.

My problem is that my P Controller uses methods inside the Thread Drive. Therefore, when I see an obstacle I cannot do:

```
if (obstacle){    
  Drive.wait();
  while(isAvoiding){
    pControler();
  }
}
Drive.Notify();


private void pController(){
  //use methods inside the DriveThread
}
```

How can I go around this problem? In other words, how can I stop the current action of my robot, avoid the block and then continue what I was doing?

Comment: Are we talking about `java.lang.Thread`s here? Because you aren't supposed to call `wait()` and `notify()` on thread objects at all.

Comment: Methods are on objects, whether that object represents a thread shouldn't stop it from neing called by another thread.  And why split out functionality into 2 threads if one has to stop the other before it can work? I don't know anything about robotics but this makes me question how things are organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interrupt the Drive Thread using Thread.interrupt() if an obstacle is in the path. Then you can compute how to deal with the obstacle and then Drive again.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--

You will have to catch the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html in the Drive thread and decide what to do then. Since i do not know how your robot works i would recommend to just stop the thread then. You can start another Drive threat after computing how to deal with the obstacle.